# Reverse Integer (Leetcode)

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, reverse

I was trying to solve 7.Reverse Integer on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-integer/.

Given a signed 32-bit integer x, return x with its digits reversed. If reversing x causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range [-2^31, 2^31 - 1], then return 0.

**Example 1:**

```
Input: x = 123  
Output: 321
```

My solution for the above problem is

```
class Solution {  
    public int reverse(int x) {  
        int num=0;  
        if(x>Integer.MAX_VALUE||x<Integer.MIN_VALUE) return 0;  
        while(x!=0){  
            int a=x%10;  
            num=num*10+a;  
            x=x/10;  
            
            
        }  
        return num;  
    }  
}
```

I'm getting 4 test cases wrong. One of which is :

**Example**

```
Input: 1534236469  
Output : 1056389759  
Expected: 0
```

Comment: You need to think about integer overflow and how to avoid it.  The expected answer of 0 tells you that a simple reversal falls out of range.

Comment: "If reversing x causes the value to go outside the signed 32-bit integer range [-2^31, 2^31 - 1], then return 0."

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the overflow is in the `num` variable and you are not checking for that.  By adding a check to make sure the calculation will not overflow before performing `num = num * 10 + a`, you can return `0` when necessary.

Also, you weren't handling negative numbers properly.  A check for a negative up front can allow you to work with a positive number and then just negate the result.

```
class Solution {  
    public int reverse(int x) {  
        int num = 0;  
        Boolean negative = false;
        
        if (x == Integer.MIN_VALUE) return 0;
        if (x < 0) {
            x = -x;
            negative = true;
        }
        while (x != 0) {  
            int a = x % 10; 
            // Check if the next operation is going to cause an overflow
            // and return 0 if it does
            if (num > (Integer.MAX_VALUE - a) / 10) return 0;
            num = num * 10 + a;  
            x = x / 10;  
        }  
        return negative ? -num : num;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not dealing with the theoretical signed 32-bit integer overflow that might occur in the loop, meaning you'll sometimes return a number outside of that range. Also, the logic will not work as expected with negative values.

And to be really precise on the restriction of signed 32-bit, special care needs to be taken when the input is -2<sup>31</sup>, as its absolute value does not represent a valid signed 32-bit integer.

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        if (x < 0) return x == -2147483648 ? 0 : -reverse(-x);
        int res = 0;
        while (x > 0 && res < 214748364) {
            res = res * 10 + x % 10;
            x /= 10;
        }
        return x == 0 ? res
             : res > 214748364 || x > 7 ? 0
             : res * 10 + x;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach you've chosen is not that far off.

1. You currently check the input `x` to be in range of unsigned integer. But they ask to check x-reversed instead.
2. You aggregate your answer in an integer, hence you might overflow unnoticed.

Both of your problems can be solved if you aggregate your result `num` in an variable of type long instead and reject/zero the answer if after reversing it is out of bounds of unsigned int.

Alternative you can use Math.addExact(a, b), Math.multiplyExact(a,b) and a try-catch to exit immediately upon overflow.

Answer (score 1):

**Input: 123
Output: 321
Input: -123
Output: -321
Input: 120
Output: 2**

class Solution {
public:
int reverse(int x) {

```
    int rev = 0;

    constexpr int top_limit = INT_MAX/10;

    constexpr int bottom_limit = INT_MIN/10;

    while (x) {

        if (rev > top_limit || rev < bottom_limit)

            return 0;

        rev = rev * 10 + x % 10;

        x /= 10;
    }
    return rev;
}
```

};

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Comment: Doesn't look like Java...